# regepx - odd whitespaces in string

Tags: php, regex

I'm doing some regexp on some strings and in my pattern I match for whitespaces `\s`

But in some strings I experience some strange spaces.. When converted to hex `a0`

How to convert all strange spaces to a normal space so it can be detected with regexp and both  and `\s`?

When the string is presented as UTF8 all `a0` chars are represented as a `�`

## input in HEX

```
a03535a03832a03834a03135a02da053452e6e723aa0444ba03132a03638a03336a03933
```

## input as string

```
 55 82 84 15 - SE.nr: DK 12 68 36 93
```

Comment: If that's coming from HTML, `A0` is `&nbsp;` ... you're not, by any chance, parsing data from a WYSIWYG editor are you?

Comment: Does it mean you seek a regex to match all whitespaces? Like `'/\s/u'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a0` is a representation of `&nbsp;` - non-breaking space.

You can match it with:

```
[\s\xA0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to add the non-breaking space to the `[\s]` character class, `\s` can match any Unicode whitespace if you use a `/u` modifier:

```
'/\s/u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kE7fS5/1)

From [pcre.org](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> The default "space" characters are HT (9), LF (10), VT (11),  FF  (12), CR  (13),  and space (32)...
>   **If PCRE is  compiled  with  Unicode  property  support,  and  the `PCRE_UCP`  option is set**, the behaviour is changed so that **Unicode properties are used** to determine character types: *`\s`  any character that matches `\p{Z}` or `\h` or `\v`*

The `PCRE_UCP` verb and Unicode semantics are enabled with the `/u` modifier.